# Duplicate MySQL database without shell

Tags: mysql, database, shell, ubuntu

I crashed my first Ubuntu installation by changing some distribution stuff (now stuck in login loop, even in shell).

So I installed Ubuntu again on my second hard drive from which I can access the crashed Ubuntu setup.

And since I can't start Apache2 or reach the MySQL server there anymore, I'm wondering if there is a possibility to duplicate the MySQL data just by copying files from one hard drive to another.

Or maybe someone has an alternative idea to restore the MySQL data?

Comment: Can you do an upgrade or some sort of repair installation onto the original disk to reinstate the system?  That won't zero everything out, so the original data may be accessible once more.

Comment: For now I could restore my database following the answer below. But in the next days I will try to repair my first Ubuntu installation, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Found out (via error log in the root dir) that the bash file in my bin folder was missing. Just copied it from latest Ubuntu installation and finally there's no login loop anymore - no idea how I got it disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a database of the same name on the other computer and then transfer the content of `/var/lib/mysql/_dbname_/`. Stop before the copying and start after it.

Comment: **Caveat**: this *only* works if the tables are MyISAM. It does not work with InnoDB.